# Selenium - Unable to Locate Element using Relative Xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, xpath

> Unable to Locate Element using Xpath.. xpath =  //label[contains(text(),'Create a guest user')]

Html source code :

```
  <html>
      <table class="formTable">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="formHeader">
            <tr>
              <td class="contentcell">
                 <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="1" name="Asset28"/>
                                       Create a guest user
                 </label>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </html>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could use id attribute to uniquely identify your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way instead :

```
//label[contains(.,'Create a guest user')]
```

by using `text()` the `contains()` function will be evaluated against first text node child of `<label>`, which in this case an empty text node (new line between `<label>` and `<input>` I suppose). This is why the element was not found.